# Is it possible to send syslog and SNMP traps to two different addresses concurrently?

Tags: cisco, snmp, syslog, nms

I am migrating our NMS and I need to assign a new different IP address to the server I am migrating to. One concern I have is that I want to make sure that all nodes I am monitoring are set up to send syslog and SNMP traps to the new address, I could just add config to point the nodes at the new syslog and trap destination but am cocerned that I can't send syslog and SNMP traps to two different addresses concurrently. Can't seem to find any documentation to back this up?

I'd like to configure nodes to send to two different addresses then when I have successfully cutover I can remove references to the old address I am migrating from.

Can I send syslog and traps to two different location sconcurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can with Cisco gear at least (and probably also with most other vendors).

For syslog:

```
logging 10.1.1.1
logging 10.1.1.2
```

For SNMP traps:

```
snmp-server host 10.1.1.1 version 2c @str!ng
snmp-server host 10.1.1.2 version 2c @str!ng
```

Comment: Cheers, John K.